# Amazon S3 Upload using NSURLSession in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, nsurlsession

I've been doing a application which involves uploading videos to S3(comparatively large size) using AWS iOS SDK enabling background mode/fetch.

However I have observed that the background upload task continues for a while approx 3 mins and then it gets suspended/app gets killed.

MyApp[2548] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
identifier: Background Content Fetching (66) process: MyApp[2548] permittedBackgroundDuration: 30.000000 reason: backgroundContentFetching owner pid:33 preventSuspend preventThrottleDownUI preventIdleSleep preventSuspendOnSleep 
)}

The issue is very much explained in here https://trovepromo-tf.trove-st...

The answer given here "If you do not call the completionHandler within 30 seconds your app will crash in the background" seems right. So Ive implemented `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:` in my VC and

```
handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:
```

in AppDelegate.

However the problem is still that the upload gets suspended after 3 minutes( I think OS does this)

My understanding is that URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession: delegate is called before this shutdown/suspension. Am I right about this?

Is there anyway I could continue the upload from inside the `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession`: 
somehow?

Or is there any automatic way that the upload process continues regardless of the fact that app has been woken up and put back to sleep.